# unable to boot due to moved root directory

Tags: linux, busybox, parrot-os, initramfs-tools

I'm currently running ParrotOS in VMWare Workstations 15 Player. Running `uname -r` returns `5.5.0-1parrot1-amd64`.

I was testing some py code that managed files in a subDirectory under ~/Downloads/htb/Challenges/. When I ran the code I was no longer able to type basic commands in the terminal or access certain programs. When I rebooted the system I could no longer boot into ParrotOS. Instead it would boot up to an initramfs console.

This is a new account so I don't have rep to post photos. Here's the output of selecting recovery mode:

recoverMode output screenshot:
[image]

I ran `find / -name sbin 2>/dev/null`  and found that the folders were moved from the root directory to ~/Downloads/htb/Challenges/ using the test data I gave it.

I tried moving those directories back to / . e.g. `mv routeToSubDir/bin /usr/bin`, however I received the error that mv can't remove the directory as it is a Read only system

Here is a list of the folders/files that are residing in the unintended subDirectory:

SubDir list screenshot:
[image]

Any input on restoring the Operating System would be appreciated. If not, at least being able to extract certain files off the VM, i.e. documents etc. would be good, but not my preferred.

Comment: Normally regular users cannot break a Linux OS this way because they cannot modify `/`. The lesson is: "testing some py code" should not be done by root. If the code really requires root access then *testing* should be done in an expendable system.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the computer, when grub will display list of systems, choose parrot, press e.

From the grub options, find the line that starts with “linux16” and go to the end of it. Type ‘rd.break’ without quotes at the end of this line, as shown below.

```
rd.break
```

Press ctrl+x

Type :

```
mount -o remount,rw /sysroot/
```

Make sure there is no space between remount and comma symbol.

Then type:

```
chrooot /sysroot/
```

Move then the directory to previous place.

If you are using SELinux in enforcing mode, you can check this with command

```
sestatus
```

Then you need to relabel files after moving them. This can be done:

```
touch /.autorelabel
```

Make sure there is no space between slash and dot.

Comment: there was no line that started with "linux16", however, there was a line starting with "linux" , so I followed the instructions on that. When I executed ```mount -o remount,rw /sysroot/``` , I receive the message ```mount: can't find /sysroot/ in /proc/mounts```

Comment: It is OK. See this link : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152029/why-is-there-no-rootfs-file-system-present-on-my-system

Comment: When you will finish, type umount /sysroot/ and then type reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Second option is to enter rescue mode instead rd.break.

Press “e” and then go the end of line which starts with word “linux” and append “systemd.unit=rescue.target“. Remove the word “$vt_handoff ” if it exists. Remove rd.break if it is there.

Mount main drive

Change sdb2 to the root partition of your drive.

```
mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt
```

Mount other stuff

```
mount -t proc none /mnt/proc 
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev 
mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sys 
mount -o bind /run /mnt/run
```

If you want to, you can mount the boot partition.  Change sdb1 if your boot partition is something else.  For efi, you may need to mount the boot partition then mount the efi partition inside /boot/efi.

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/boot
```

Chroot

```
chroot /mnt
```

You should now be inside the chroot environment.  To exit the chroot, hit control+d or type exit.

Of course remember to umount drives before exit.